# CSS change label background of another element, when radio button is checked

Tags: css, background-color

I want to change the background color of the label class 'label-status', depending on if the radio button is set to agree or disagree.

```
<div class="testclass">
    <label class="label-status">Status</label>
    <label class="radio-inline" style="display:inline-block;"><input type="radio" name="status" disabled="">Agree</label>
    <label class="radio-inline" style="display:inline-block;"><input type="radio" name="status" checked="" disabled="">Disagree</label>
</div>
```

Since it's not my website, but some custom user CSS I want to inject to make it more usable, I cannot make any changes to the actual html.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Give the input's id's then use javascript to detect if the radio button is selected or not and change the css background color element using js.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the `order` *property* (*Flexbox* or *Grid*) together with the `for` *attribute* to link the `label` with the related `input` element:

```css
.testclass {display: flex} /* displays flex-items (children) inline; can also use the "inline-flex" which only takes the content's width */

.label-status {order: -1} /* puts it back to the desired place (above other siblings); the initial value is set to 0 */

.testclass > input:first-of-type:checked ~ .label-status {background: green}
.testclass > input:last-of-type:checked ~ .label-status {background: red}
```

```html
<div class="testclass">
  <input type="radio" name="status" id="agree">
  <label for="agree">Agree</label>
  <input type="radio" name="status" id="disagree" checked>
  <label for="disagree">Disagree</label>
  <label class="label-status">Status</label> <!-- needs to be placed below other siblings in order to take advantage of the "~" selector -->
</div>
```

Then you can use the *[general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)* `~` to *target* the `.label-status` with e.g. `:first-of-type` & `:last-of-type` *selectors* set on the `input` *elements*, of course in conjunction with the `:checked` *pseudo-class selector*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JS, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".label-status").on("click",function() {
            if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) { 
          $('.radio-inline').removeClass('sel_bk_color');
          $(this).addClass('sel_bk_color');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is an example of this kind of thing in action: https://jsfiddle.net/tr9Lyxz3/1/

Answer (score 0):

By default your inputs are disabled. you have to first remove disable property and then add onclick attributes to run a function which will change background color.

```
 document.getElementsByName('status')[0].removeAttribute("disabled")
 document.getElementsByName('status')[1].removeAttribute("disabled")
 document.getElementsByClassName('radio-inline')[0].setAttribute("onclick","myFunction()")
 document.getElementsByClassName('radio-inline')[1].setAttribute("onclick","myFunction()")
 function myFunction(){
    if (document.getElementsByName('status')[1].checked) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("label-status")[0].classList.remove("myclass2")
        document.getElementsByClassName("label-status")[0].classList.add("myclass1");
    }
    else if (document.getElementsByName('status')[0].checked) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("label-status")[0].classList.remove("myclass1")
        document.getElementsByClassName("label-status")[0].classList.add("myclass2");
    }
 }
```

you have to define your css for myclass1 and myclass2 as per your background color requirement.

this is not possible using pure css as you cant read values dynamically using css. so if you can use js then this will solve your problem without editing html.

Answer (score 0):

Some pure CSS solutions seem to miss the you are not allowed to change the HTML.

Are you allowed to use javascript?

Here is some javascript without JQuery:

```
    var updateLabel = function(e) {
          var label = document.getElementsByClassName("label-status")[0];
          if (e.target !== e.currentTarget && event.target.type === "radio") {
            if(e.target.labels[0].innerText === "Agree") {
              label.style.background = "green"
            } else {
              label.style.background = "red";
            }
          }
          e.stopPropagation();
        }

    var wrapperElement = document.getElementsByClassName("testclass")[0];
    wrapperElement.addEventListener("click", updateLabel, false);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXWJXK

You do have to remove the disabled attribute from your radio buttons. With javascript you can use element.removeAttribute("disabled").

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buttons {
    display: flex
    align-item: center;
}

.condition {
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.status {
    order: -1;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.buttons > input:first-of-type:checked ~ .status {
    background: green;
}
.buttons > input:last-of-type:checked ~ .status {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="agree">
    <label for="agree" class="condition">Agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="disagree" checked>
    <label for="disagree" class="condition">Disagree</label>
    <label class="status">Status</label>
</div>
```